# GWT FileUpload initial path

Tags: gwt, widget

Is there a way to set the initial path for the FileUpload widget in GWT.
So the next time the user presses the browse button he is put to the location he has been the last time (if existent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK apparently there is a attribute but which is not supported for various reasons, as we can read [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html#value).

Apart from that it would be really useful for paths (not file names), so the user doesn't have to browse to the same location when he is uploading multiple files.